# Gradle Fat Jar Plugin and Spring: Error Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource

Tags: java, xml, spring, gradle, spring-ldap

After build my application with grade fat jar plugin as is configured bellow:

```
task fatJar(type: Jar) {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'PACMAN',
                'Implementation-Version': version,
                'Main-Class': 'com.y.y.z.Mainclass'
    }
    baseName = project.name + '-all'
    from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
    with jar
}
```

And running this app (fat-jar with all dependencies) as follow:

```
-bash-3.2$ java -Dconf.properties=/app/home/wasa/sat/bin/app.properties -jar app-all-1.0.jar
```

Two thinks happens:

First is received the spring bootstrap start messages:

```
11/01/2016 11:38:59 org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@11f23e5: startup date 
[Mon Jan 11 11:38:59 BRST 2016]; root of context hierarchy

11/01/2016 11:39:00 org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [applicationContext.xml]
```

And then after a while thi error/exception raises as described bellow:

```
11/01/2016 11:42:12 org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader warning
Ignored XML validation warning
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 
'http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd', because 
1) could not find the document; 
2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:195)
...
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:287)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:76)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadDocument(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:429)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:391)
```

I also have tried to download the spring-beans.xsd file definition and included it in the resources folder in my project without success.

I'm load the spring xml configuration files as showed bellow:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    AbstractApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
    getAllActiveUsersInPeople(context);
}
```

My appicationContext.xml is defined as bellow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:ldap="http://www.springframework.org/schema/ldap"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/ldap http://www.springframework.org/schema/ldap/spring-ldap.xsd">
```

Someone has the similar problem or a possible solution to fix this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Have you added the spring jars to your classpath?

Comment: @Jens classpath with gradle fat jar?

Comment: all libs are inside the result jar

Comment: Manifest-Version: 1.0
Rsrc-Class-Path: ./ aopalliance-1.0.jar commons-lang-2.3.jar commons-l
 ogging-1.2.jar guava-19.0-rc1.jar logback-classic-1.1.3.jar logback-c
 ore-1.1.3.jar pacman.jar slf4j-api-1.7.12.jar spring-aop-4.2.1.RELEAS
 E.jar spring-beans-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar spring-context-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar
  spring-core-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar spring-data-commons-core-1.4.1.RELEASE
 .jar spring-expression-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar spring-ldap-core-2.0.3.RELEA
 SE.jar spring-tx-3.2.13.RELEASE.jar
Class-Path: .
Rsrc-Main-Class: com.tim.pcs.app.PacBiru
Main-Class: org.eclipse.jdt.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader